# Matplotlib window slows down

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm making *Conway's Game Of Life*. Here is code that I have written so far:

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cols, rows = 100, 100
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
draw = True
FULL = 0
pause = 0.005
minor_ticks =  (np.arange(-0.5, cols-0.5, 1), np.arange(-0.5, rows-0.5, 1))
play = True
randomGrid = 1


def limitCheckCells(arr):
    limitArr = []
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        for y in range(len(arr[x])):
            if arr[x, y]==1:
                for i in range(x-1, x+2):
                    for j in range(y-1, y+2):
                        if i>=cols:
                            i-=cols
                        if j>=rows:
                            j-=rows
                        limitArr.append((i, j))
    return(set(limitArr))


def press(event):
    global play
    if event.key == 'enter':
        draw = False
        print(play)
    if event.key == ' ':
        if play:
            play = False
        else:
            play = True
        print(play)


def update(arr):
    ax.matshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.gray)


def make2Darray(cols, rows):
    if FULL:
        mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        mng.full_screen_toggle()

    if randomGrid:
        arr = np.random.randint(2, size=[cols, rows])
    else:
        arr = np.zeros([cols, rows])
    ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks[0], minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks[1], minor=True)
    ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.05)
    update(arr)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
    while draw:
        try:
            x, y = plt.ginput()[0]
        except:
            break
        x, y = round(y), round(x)
        if arr[x, y] == 0: arr[x, y] = 1
        else: arr[x, y] = 1

        ax.fill(x-0.5, y-0.5,'w', x+0.5, y+0.5, 'w')
        # update(arr)

    return arr


def countNeightbors(grid, x, y):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            xn, yn = x+i, y+j

            if xn>=cols and yn>=rows:
                xn-=cols
                yn-=rows
            elif xn>=cols:
                xn-=cols
            elif yn>=rows:
                yn-=rows

            sum+=grid[xn, yn]
    sum-=grid[x, y]
    return sum


def main():
    grid = make2Darray(cols, rows)
    grid2 = np.zeros([cols, rows])

    gen=0
    while True:
        ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
        plt.pause(pause)
        if not play:
            plt.waitforbuttonpress()

        gen += 1
        print('\r', end='')
        print(f'generation = {gen}', end='')

        checklList = limitCheckCells(grid)
        # print(len(checlList))
        if len(checklList)==0:
            print('The world is DEAD')
            sys.exit(0)

        for i, j in checklList:
            nbrs = countNeightbors(grid, i, j)
            cell = grid[i, j]
            if cell == 1 and (nbrs<2 or nbrs>3):
                cell = 0
            elif cell == 0 and nbrs == 3:
                cell = 1

            grid2[i, j] = cell

        grid = grid2.copy()


    # plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that when I start the compilation the speed of changing generations is ok but as time is going the window is slowing down a lot. And it's due to the code because when I close the window and code is still compiling the speed of changing generations is a lot faster than I was at the beginning.
I don't know how to fix it so the speed will be the same all the time. I was looking for the function that connect the array with the plt window but didn't find anything except `plt.imshow()` and `plt.matshow()`. I think these functions are slow by them own but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An educated guess is you're plotting new images on top of each other and MPL ends up drawing all of them over time. You might need to clear the subplot before adding a new plot to it.

**EDIT:** I refactored your code a little to a more minimal example without global variables.

At present it's missing the ability to modify the grid with the mouse, but that should be easy enough to re-add). It retains the pace of about 0.15 seconds per iteration, most of which is spent in MPL, as is evident when you close the MPL window...

```
import time
from itertools import count

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def limit_cells_to_check(grid):
    cols, rows = grid.shape
    limitArr = set()
    for x in range(cols):
        for y in range(rows):
            if grid[x, y] == 1:
                for i in range(x - 1, x + 2):
                    for j in range(y - 1, y + 2):
                        i %= cols
                        j %= rows
                        limitArr.add((i, j))
    return limitArr


def count_neighbors(grid, x, y):
    cols, rows = grid.shape
    sum = 0
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            xn, yn = x + i, y + j
            xn %= cols
            yn %= rows
            sum += grid[xn, yn]
    sum -= grid[x, y]
    return sum


def run_iteration(grid):
    checklist = limit_cells_to_check(grid)
    if not checklist:
        print("The world is DEAD")
        return None

    grid2 = grid.copy()

    for i, j in checklist:
        neighbors = count_neighbors(grid, i, j)
        cell = grid[i, j]
        if cell == 1 and (neighbors < 2 or neighbors > 3):
            cell = 0
        elif cell == 0 and neighbors == 3:
            cell = 1

        grid2[i, j] = cell

    return grid2


def update(ax, arr):
    ax.cla()
    ax.matshow(arr, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.pause(0.001)


def initialize_display(cols, rows):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    minor_ticks = (np.arange(-0.5, cols - 0.5, 1), np.arange(-0.5, rows - 0.5, 1))
    ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks[0], minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks[1], minor=True)
    ax.grid(which="minor", alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.05)
    return ax


def main():
    cols, rows = 100, 100
    ax = initialize_display(cols, rows)
    grid = np.random.randint(2, size=[cols, rows])

    for gen in count(1):
        t0 = time.time()
        update(ax, grid)
        new_grid = run_iteration(grid)
        if new_grid is None:
            break
        grid = new_grid
        g_time = time.time() - t0
        print(f"generation = {gen}, time={g_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I tryed to add this fuction and checked the time that takes per one loop operation. Here are the results: generation = 50, time = 1.548... with ax.cla(). generation = 50, time = 1.597... without ax.cla(). Doesn't seem that it's a lot better. I also tryed ax.clear() but the time at the 50th generation was roughly the same. P.S.: I tested it on 50 by 50 grid

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you have a separate ax.matshow in the other loop... you should change that too.

Comment: You're welcome. You can get additional speedups by using eg. `np.argwhere()`, which returns the coordinates of cells that are nonzero, etc...